# Reshape data frame by vector

Tags: r, quanteda

Lets say a function called `textstat_frequency{package:quanteda}`
gives us following data frame.

```
data.frame(xx=1:4,yy=5:8,foo=c("A","A","B","C"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  xx  yy  foo
1  1  5   A
2  2  6   A
3  3  7   B
4  4  8   C
```

What's the best way to shape the data.frame according the vector
`c("B","A","C")`. I have made an index with `match` or `%in%` but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(xx=1:4,yy=5:8,foo=c("A","A","B","C"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
temp = factor(df$foo, levels = c("B", "A", "C"))
df = df[order(temp),]
df
#  xx yy foo
#3  3  7   B
#1  1  5   A
#2  2  6   A
#4  4  8   C
```